# Saving Windows shortcut gives me an error

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to edit a windows shortcut file using Python 3.3

```
import sys
import os
import win32com.client 

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(r'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyApp.lnk')
old_target = shortcut.Targetpath

new_target = r'C:\MyApp.exe'

shortcut.TargetPath = new_target
shortcut.save()
```

but I get this error which I try to run this script from cmd

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'WshShortcut.Save', 'Unable to save shortcut "C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\MyApp.lnk".', None, 0, -2147024891), None)
```

I saw similar pieces of codes online which worked. what is wrong with this code and how to make it work successfully.

Comment: This can't be your actual code, because you're going to get a `NameError` on that `old_shortcut` before you even get to the point where you're trying to save the new shortcut. If you want us to debug your code, please show us your actual code.

Comment: Also, is `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` actually a real directory, and do you have write access there? (You can test this by just running `with open(r'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('hello')`. Generally Python's built-in functions give more readable errors than win32com if the same problem arises.)

Comment: Finally, while COM can occasionally be forgiving of capitalization errors, in general capitalization counts in programming. So call [`CreateShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.84).aspx), not `CreateShortCut`, and access the `TargetPath`, not the `Targetpath`, and so on.

Comment: One more thing: if you want to access the desktop folder, `shell.SpecialFolders('Desktop')` is easier than hardcoding the path, and more portable as well.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert . By executing your piece of code I noticed that I donot have the permission to edit my desktop. Any suggestion to run this script as an administrator ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried it with both `Save` and `save` but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Do you really want to write to `C:\Users\Public`? Or do you want to write to your user's desktop?

Comment: The shortcut which I want to edit has the path as `C:\Users\Public`

Comment: Then you will have to elevate your script.

Comment: If you're trying to edit an existing shortcut, you _also_ need to have write permission to the shortcut itself, not just the folder it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if your process has write access to the location where you are trying to save the file. Either:

1. Run the process elevated, or
2. Save the shortcut in a location where you have write access.

I suspect that it would make more sense for you to choose option 2 and save the shortcut under the user profile.